# How do I resolve the package name for google play when testing locally for Facebook login

Tags: react-native, facebook, google-play-console

I am trying to add Facebook login locally so I have not yet published the app, as I'm still working on the login screen, but I receive this error when trying to setup up a Facebook app:

[image]

I have an account with google play store which I have also created and app within google play.

So how does this work?

Comment: Try to use some another real package name in this place and after release change for your.